# Why is MSVC preprocessor concatenating tokens differently than GCC and Clang?

Tags: c, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

Recently, I came across a problem with MSVC. Here is a minimal example of it.

```
#define NUMBERSIGNS(a,b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a,b) NUMBERSIGNS(a,b) 
#define AA
#define BB  
CONCAT(B, CONCAT(A, A B))
```

What I am thinking:

Since arguments preceded or followed by `##` will not be expanded, I need a `NUMBERSIGNS(a,b)` macro to wrap up the `##`, and call it with `CONCAT(a,b)`, so  the arguments get expanded before they are concatenated.

When `CONCAT(B, CONCAT(A, A B))` gets expanded, I expect the inner `CONCAT(A, A B)` gets expanded to `AA B`, yielding `CONCAT(B, AA B)`.

Then we expand `AA` to   and we get `CONCAT(B, B)` (I guess MSVC did not do this step, and I don't know if it should).

Then we have `BB` which is rescanned and expanded to  .

Preprocessed by gcc and clang the code yields empty, which is my desired result:

while MSVC gives:

```
BAA B
```

Is this a bug of MSVC or am I writing an undefined behavior?

EDIT:

> Thanks to the answers, where the problem was has been identified. MSVC did not conform to the Standard.
>
> However, recently it seems they started to take the Standard seriously and added **a new `/Zc:preprocessor` option** to enable a full conforming mode of their C/C++ preprocessor. See:
> [Announcing full support for a C/C++ conformant preprocessor in MSVC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/announcing-full-support-for-a-c-c-conformant-preprocessor-in-msvc/)

Comment: MSVC preprocessor is notoriously non-conforming. It acts on a sequence of characters, not a sequence of tokens. The simple example is `#define N(x) -x    N(N(1))` . [MSVC fails](https://godbolt.org/z/SHTtQb) since the output of the preprocessor is `--` `1` (a `--` token followed by `1` token), and you can't decrement an rvalue. [clang succeeds](https://godbolt.org/z/r8rW9A) as the preprocessor produces three tokens `-` `-` `1`, so it's simply a unary negation applied twice.

Comment: Disregarding the compilers, if this was given to you in a test, what would your answer have been?  I would have expected  "B B"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.3.1 1 specifies macro argument substitution:

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

In `CONCAT` `(` `B` `,` `CONCAT` `(` `A` `,` `A` `B` `)` `)`, the first `CONCAT` macro has arguments `B` and `CONCAT` `(` `A` `,` `A` `B` `)`. These arguments are completely macro replaced first.

`B` is not a macro, so it remains `B`.

In `CONCAT` `(` `A` `,` `A` `B` `)`, the arguments `A` and `A` `B` are completely macro replaced, but they are not macros, so they remain `A` and `A` `B`.

Then `CONCAT` `(` `A` `,` `A` `B` `)` is replaced by `NUMBERSIGNS` `(` `A` `,` `A` `B` `)`.

Then 6.10.3.4 1 tells us:

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and `#` and `##` processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.

So `NUMBERSIGNS` `(` `A` `,` `A` `B` `)` is replaced by `A` `##` `A` `B`. Then the tokens before and after the `##` are concatenated, forming `AA` `B` (per 6.10.3.3 3).

This sequence `AA` `B` is then again rescanned, per 6.10.3.4 1. Since `AA` is a macro, it is replaced with no tokens, leaving just `B`. This completes the expansion of the second argument of the first `CONCAT`.

Thus, after argument substitution, we have `CONCAT` `(` `B` `,` `B` `)`.

Now `CONCAT` is replaced, forming `NUMBERSIGNS` `(` `B` `,` `B` `)`.

Since `NUMBERSIGNS` is a macro, this is replaced by `B` `##` `B`. Then the tokens before and after `##` are concatenated, forming `BB`.

This is rescanned, and `BB` is replaced with no tokens.

The final result is no tokens. GCC is correct, and MSVC’s result does not conform to the C standard.